# Moduli space of differential forms

Tags: differential-forms, grassmannian, moduli-space

In [this paper](http://www.cmls.polytechnique.fr/perso/voisin/Articlesweb/HyperCrelleFinal.pdf), Debarre-Voisin refer to the "moduli space" of differential 3-forms $\sigma \in \bigwedge^3(V_{10}^*)$ on a fixed vector space $V_{10}$ of dimension 10, and state that this space is $\mathbb{P}\left( \bigwedge^3(V_{10}^*) \right) // PGL(V_{10}^*)$. The authors also suggest that "a dimension count" reveals that the dimension of this moduli space is 20. (I suppose that the double slash refers to a GIT quotient.)

Is there a relatively simple way of understanding what this space is, and why exactly it parameterizes differential 3-forms on $V_{10}$? What about its dimension?

Comment: You start with all 3-forms, then quotient by scaling, then again by changes of coordinate. That's all the definition is saying.

Comment: And the dimension count is simply the standard way of figuring out the dimension of the quotient of a manifold by a Lie group. It is explained in detail in Lee's bookon smooth manifolds, for example.